# Haskell Rank1Types and parentheses -- strange behaviour

Tags: haskell, higher-rank-types

Switching on `RankNTypes` (without which these signatures won't get accepted, because they're not Haskell 98, [says the User Guide](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/8.10.2/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#arbitrary-rank-polymorphism)), and `-fprint-explicit-foralls` so I can see the quantification, consider:

```
foo :: b -> (Eq c => c)              -- inferred foo :: forall {c} {b}. Eq c => b -> c
foo x = undefined

bar :: b -> (Eq b => b)              -- inferred bar :: forall {b}. Eq b => b -> b
bar x = undefined

bar2 :: b -> (forall b. Eq b => b)   --          bar2 :: forall {b1} {b}. Eq b1 => b -> b1
bar2 x = undefined
```

OK so far: these are all Rank 1 Types. GHC (version 8.6.5) has shunted the constraint to the front of the signature; for `bar` 'commonned' the scope of same-named `b`; for `bar2` *not* commonned the scope because there's an explicit `forall` in the given signature, so that's name-shadowing.

```
barbar :: b -> (Eq b => b) -> (Show b => b)  --  barbar :: forall {b}. Show b => b -> (Eq b => b) -> b
barbar x y = undefined

barbar2 :: b -> Eq b => b -> (Show b => b)   --  barbar2 :: forall {b}. (Eq b, Show b) => b -> b -> b
barbar2 x y = undefined
```

What's going on with the inferred signature for `barbar`? That nested `-> (Eq b => b) ->` is not H98. Does that mean the `b` is not commonned? No:

```
*Main> barbar 'c' True
<interactive>:36:12: error:
    * Couldn't match expected type `Char' with actual type `Bool'
```

So `barbar, barbar2` are Rank 1 and have the same effective signature -- or do they?

**Addit:** (in response to answers)

```
barbar4 :: b -> (Eq b => b -> (Show b => b)) --  barbar4 :: forall {b}. (Eq b, Show b) => b -> b -> b
barbar4 x y = undefined
```

`barbar, barbar4` are equivalent? So `Eq b =>` in `barbar` scopes over everything to the right. Then I can see that's Rank-1. Whereas the closing parens nested in the given signature for `barbar2` is not merely decoration.

Answer (score 1):

These two types are different. Observe this GHCi session. First, we define your functions.
I used `Num` instead of `Eq` to better explain what's going on.

```
> barbar :: b -> (Num b => b) -> (Show b => b) ; barbar _ _ = undefined
> :t barbar
barbar :: forall {b}. Show b => b -> (Num b => b) -> b

> barbar2 :: b -> Num b => b -> (Show b => b) ; barbar2 _ _ = undefined
> :t barbar2
barbar2 :: forall {b}. (Num b, Show b) => b -> b -> b
```

No surprise, here. Now, we apply both functions choosing `b ~ String`, which does not satisfy `Num`. This type checks:

```
> :t barbar "hello" 5
barbar "hello" 5 :: [Char]
```

This does not:

```
> :t barbar2 "hello" 5
    * No instance for (Num [Char]) arising from a use of `barbar2'
    * In the expression: barbar2 "hello" 5
```

Why? In the first case, it's `barbar` that has to ensure `Num b`: the caller can exploit that guarantee to craft the argument. Above, `5` is converted to `b` (i.e., `String`) thanks to the provided constraint.

In the second case, it's the caller to `barbar2` that has to ensure `Num b`, so we can not choose `b ~ String`.

Now, one might wonder how can `barbar` provide the `Num b` constraint for a generic `b`. Indeed, that's impossible since non-numeric types exist. However, we only need to do that if we actually use the second argument in `barbar`. We don't, so the type checker is satisfied.

Indeed, if we try to use the second argument, we do get an error:

```
> barbar3 :: b -> (Num b => b) -> (Show b => b) ; barbar3 _ y = y
    * Could not deduce (Num b) arising from a use of `y'
```

Comment: Ok so your `barbar` with `Num` exploits that literal `5` as second argument desugars to a polymorphic `(fromInteger <something> ) :: forall {p}. Num p => p`. Because `barbar` doesn't inspect its second arg (not even its type), so it's relaxed that the wanted `Num` from `5` is discharged by the 'localised' `Num` (for want of a better word) in `barbar`'s signature. `barbar` is still Rank-1? And yet the `Num b` doesn't scope over the same scope as tyvar `b`? I'm not able to see the sense, even if I squint quite a bit.

Comment: @AntC I'd call that a rank-1 type, I think. You can see that type as if it were `b -> (NumDict b -> b) -> ShowDict b -> b` where we can see the explicit dictionaries carrying the "proof that `b` is in the class". So we have access to the dictionary in the second argument, but not in the first one.

Comment: Thanks heh heh. I think these should be called rank one-and-a-half. Problem: both yours and @leftroundabout's answers here make sense, but I can only green tick one of them.

Answer (score 1):

The `b` *is* “commonned”, but the `Eq` constraint is not. This is generally not a useful configuration, but it's in principle possible; here's an example:

```
rhubarb :: b -> (Eq b => b) -> b
rhubarb x _ = x
```

```
> rhubarb id id 3 :: Int
3
```

Note that second `id` argument has type `Eq (Int -> Int) => Int -> Int`, which is nonsense... but it doesn't matter, because that type is strictly less general than `Int -> Int`. Only, because `Int -> Int` *doesn't* have an `Eq` instance, `rhubarb` can't in fact use that argument in any way.

Comment: So is `rhubarb` Rank-1? If not, shouldn't I expect another `forall` somewhere? What's horribly counter-intuitive is that adding parens is supposed to be purely superficial, not change the meaning.

Comment: It is indeed Rank-1 because the only `∀` is over `b` encompassing the entire signature. — I disagree that the parenthesization part is horribly counter-intuitive; after all `(Int -> Int) -> Int` and `Int -> Int -> Int` are also entirely different types. What is counterintuitive is that a constraint detached from a quantifier is even _allowed_, because this almost never makes sense; however from a compiler perspective it is a straightforward generalisation.